# SQL Server view inside CTE causing poor performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, view, common-table-expression

When I use a view inside of a CTE, each subquery that references the CTE seems to re-query the view. There are large chunks of the execution plan that are repeated for each subquery. This isn't the case when selecting from a table. Is this expected? Is there any way to get around it?

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT v.id
    FROM test_view AS v
)
SELECT TOP 25 *,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte) AS subquery
FROM cte
```

I'm working with SQL Server 2005

EDIT:

I'm trying to get data from a view in pages with the query below. I need the total number of rows in the view, the number of rows that match a search, and a subset of the matching rows. This works well when selecting from tables, but using a view causes repeated execution of the CTE. I attempted to force intermediate materialization a variety of different ways from the link in Martin's answer, but didn't have any luck.

```
WITH tableRecords AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM example_view
),
filteredTableRecords AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS tableRecordNumber
    FROM tableRecords
    WHERE 1 = 1
)
SELECT *,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableRecords) AS totalRecords,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filteredTableRecords) AS totalDisplayRecords
FROM filteredTableRecords
WHERE tableRecordNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 25
ORDER BY tableRecordNumber ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is largely expected.

See [Provide a hint to force intermediate materialization of CTEs or derived tables](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/)

For the query in your question you can do this though

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT v.id,
       count(*) OVER () AS Cnt
FROM test_view AS v
)
SELECT TOP 25 *
FROM CTE
ORDER BY v.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and the answer. I wasn't able to force materialization of the CTE using any of the linked methods, unfortunately. Please check out my edit above, if you have a chance.

Comment: @davishmcclurg - The best way of optimizing that will depend upon the definition of the view, the size of the tables involved, the nature of the filter expression and the available indexes. There isn't one approach that will always be best.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you re-write your query as below

There are a few improvements I did over your query

1. removal of where 1=1, it is unnecessary as it is always true.
2. the sub-query in select clause will be called everytime you execute the sql script, so instead of that you can actually use the cross apply to increase the performance.

   ```
   ;WITH tableRecords AS(
   SELECT *
   FROM example_view
   ),
   filteredTableRecords AS (
         SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS tableRecordNumber
         FROM tableRecords
     ),TotalNumber
     (
          SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tableRecords) AS totalRecords,
          (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM filteredTableRecords) AS totalDisplayRecords
     )
     SELECT *
     FROM filteredTableRecords F
     CROSS APPLY TotalNumber AS T
     WHERE tableRecordNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 25
     ORDER BY tableRecordNumber ASC
   ```